# DNN Web API Server Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api, dotnetnuke

I'm repeatedly getting an Internal Server Error 500 when trying to make a simple call to a DNN Web API controller. I do not get this error on my development machine, nor do I get it on one of our deployment servers. However, one of our *other* deployment servers is the problem; and I'd like to figure out why.

Consider the following, simplistic API controller in **TheBestController.cs**

```
namespace MyTestLibrary.Controllers
{   
    public class TheBestController : DnnApiController
    {
        [DnnAuthorize]
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage TestMe()
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "I'm working");
        }

     }
}
```

With this RouteMapper in **RouteMapper.cs**

```
using DotNetNuke.Web.Api;

namespace MyTestLibrary
{
    public class RouteMapper : IServiceRouteMapper
    {
        public void RegisterRoutes(IMapRoute mapRouteManager)
        {
            mapRouteManager.MapHttpRoute("TheBestController", "default", "{controller}/{action}",  new[] { "MyTestLibrary.Controllers" });
        }
    }
}
```

With the following AJAX call from my Javascript:

```
$.post("DesktopModules/MyTestLibrary/API/TheBest/TestMe", function(data) {
        alert(data);
 });
```

I have made sure that all of the correct permissions are set for the DNN application in IIS (as well as mirrored those and all other pertinent settings that are on our server that has this working). I place the compiled **MyTestLibrary.dll** in the bin folder of the DNN site, and I place the javascript file in the Resources/Shared/scripts folder of the DNN site. The DNN site is reading the javascript with no issues, and I am not using a module (and would not like to because I want all of my code to be easily transferrable to an MVC site).

I have also tried using the `[AllowAnonymous]` tag on the controller method (to no avail).

The version of DNN on all machines is 07.01.01, and the two servers are running Server 2008 R2 64bit. The dev machine is running Win 7 64 bit.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you logged in to the environments that work, and not the one that doesn't? Logged in with a DNN account that has admin permissions?

Comment: @ChrisHammond I'm logged into DNN as host. In the deployment server that DOES have this working, I can be logged on as any user and the API calls work just fine

Comment: @ChrisHammond When a "normal" DNN module is installed to a site, do you know if there are any special authentication permissions set anywhere in the database or elsewhere in the site directory?

Comment: Not that I can think of off hand, not until you place a module on a page, then the permissions are at the module level, or page level, depending on configuration. If you login as HOST on the other environment, does it work?

Comment: @ChrisHammond Nope. And I'm temporarily (for troubleshooting purposes) giving FULL permissions in IIS and the C:\inetpub\wwwroot folder while logged into the server as a full domain and local machine admin. Don't know how much more wide open I can make it

Comment: Is there other functionality that doesn't work on that installation? I've seen where some installations of IIS have issues, but others don't. I ran into a problem on one site, where I had 20 other sites running, that the site just simply wouldn't work, but creating a new Site in IIS addressed the issue. It was around "editing" in DNN 7, but was most definitely an issue with something corrupted with the IIS site itself, not DNN.

Comment: @ChrisHammond No other functionality is not working that I'm aware of. I'm going to try to create a new, fresh site and see if my basic API controller works there.

Comment: @ChrisHammond I created the new site and everything works now. I didn't change any settings in IIS - very strange. Thanks for the tip

Comment: I wish I could tell you why that works, or the original one didn't work :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To break the comments out into an answer ;)

I've seen where IIS on Windows Server 2008 can somehow corrupt a folder that a DNN website is using, and that starts to cause issues with certain web services in DNN. Two solutions that I know have worked in the past for me.

1) Setup a new site in IIS and install DNN in that folder.
or 
2) Move the DNN files to a different folder on the server, point the existing IIS website to that folder, instead of the original one.

One of those two should hopefully work for most people that run into this problem.

Now, what exactly goes wrong in IIS and why can the existing folder be fix? No clue :(

Comment: #1 worked for me. I had previously tried #2 and that didn't work. Even though we still don't know exactly what caused it, the problem seems to be fairly rare (so far)